# Node.js framework for building a RESTful api using a relational DB as back-end

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest

I am trying to develop an API server using Node.js. The back-end for my application is postgresql DB and my API needs to communicate with the DB. The front end is a mobile App, developed in iOS/Android native language. I am planning to use **Express.js** for API and **node-postgres** for postgresql nodejs integration. Are there any better modules available for this requirement?

Comment: Is your question "Are there any better modules available for this requirement?"

Comment: Express.js for API is the best one, for PostgreSQL - [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)

Comment: @Enkode Yes, are there any better modules available? I am a new to NodeJS, so I might miss something.